# Create group ID based on description

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I had a table (Excel format) as follows:

```
**Company name**
2016 Microsoft company
2015 ANZ (north) Co.ltd
2015(south) Microsoft Co.Ltd
2016 ANZ Co.ltd
COMPANY OF FRIESLAND CAMPINA (milk) Australia
CAMPINA (Food) Co.Ltd
2015 CAMPINA (Food) Co.Ltd
2015COMPANY OF FRIESLAND CAMPINA (milk)  Indo
Co.FRIESLAND CAMPINA (milk)  Thai land
```

I would like to generate the ID based on the company name as follows:

```
Company name                                             |ID  | Notes
2016 Microsoft company                                   | 1  | Microsoft
2015 ANZ (north) Co.ltd                                  | 2  | ANZ
2015(south) Microsoft Co.Ltd                             | 1  | Microsoft
2016 ANZ Co.ltd                                          | 2  | ANZ
COMPANY OF FRIESLAND CAMPINA (milk) Australia            | 3  | Friesland campina (milk)
CAMPINA (Food) Co.Ltd                                    | 4  | Campina (Food)
2015 CAMPINA (Food) Co.Ltd                               | 4  | Campina (Food)
2015COMPANY OF FRIESLAND CAMPINA (milk)  Indo            | 3  | Friesland campina (milk)
Co.FRIESLAND CAMPINA (milk)  Thai land                   | 3  | Friesland Campina (milk)
```

There are not exact rules to define the ID, just based on the company name. In my view, I try to defining the key word of each record and then scanning through the list to find the same value containing the text. Finally, I create the ID.
 I need to create an function or script to define it automatically. It could be done with Excel VBA or SQL Server script.

In excel, I can perform this task by using the combination between Search and IF function. But It only works when the likely company recorded side by side. And I don’t know how to scan though the list by Excel function. Another issue is how to define the correct key word? I just used MID function to get the temporary key.

```
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(A2,12,8),A1)),B1,B1+1)
```

Comment: Even if someone gave you code for these rules, there could be other use cases you didn't show or didn't even know about.  Is there any chance that you could just map an ID to the text instead?

Comment: sanitise the data , there's no way that you're going to capture every company name correctly

Comment: You would need to have some sort of reference, i.e. MS being 1 ANZ being 2 in an ID's table say, then you could use an array formula with SEARCH to compare, but I agree with others, I've used MS as Microsoft for example, it wont be 100% also could have Anzac in the title :) just some examples, the reason for the ID no doubt :)

Comment: Yes, I know that the data is very messy so I just extract the "unclear  key word" by MID function, It can be absolutely exact but can reduce the manual work a lot. Another thing which I concern that how to scan through all list and create the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an array copied down to begin with something like

`=MAX(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH($C$1:$C$3,$a1))),ROW($C$1:$C$3),0))`

This would then give the results below

[image]

Comment: thanks Nathan. I will check and confirm later. If I find any solutions. I will tell you. Once again, thank you so much.